# Matrix field losing value when editing entry

Tags: matrix, field-pack, pt-dropdown

- ExpressionEngine version: 2.5.5
- Matrix version: 2.5.5
- P&T Field Pack version: 1.03

I have a channel entry that uses several Matrix fields, and one of them uses P&T Dropdown. If I publish a new entry the value from the P&T Dropdown shows up properly when viewing on the frontend. This works fine.

However, if I then go in to edit the entry, the P&T Dropdown field is now defaulting to whatever the first value is. This has caused the value to unexpectedly change if an author goes in to edit something else in the entry and does not realize that the P&T Dropdown has reset to its default value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Patrick, sorry we missed this. FFR bug reports should be sent directly to us at support@pixelandtonic.com rather than posted here.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you solely using the CP to edit your entries, or is there a SafeCracker form involved?